# Echo out text on previous page after link?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

Basically i have a favorite icon on the users profile page. Another user can press this button and it will link to favorites.php where it will carry out the sql query to add that user to the database.

This then leaves the user stuck on favorites.php faced with a blank page. What i want favorites.php to do is after its processed the query is echo out a piece of text that says user added to favorites on the previous page profile.php. but i can't simply redirect them to profile.php using header because each user profile has an id extension like profile.php?id=13 and they will have clicked on that users profile.

so my question is can i use a header to redirect to the previous page they was on (url specific) so that its that users id they was originally onwith that corresponding . can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. It can be done.  What have you tried so far to do it? Why make the user got to a howl separate page to being with (such that a redirect is required?)

Comment: well i have tried to use this:  header("Location: profile.php?"$profile_id";")

Comment: the user needs to go to a separate page because the page counts the number of times a user favorites that user.

Comment: Why couldn't that count be made on the same page the user is currently on?  I guess what I am asking, is why add unnecessary complexity?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of UI interaction is typically accomplished with AJAX calls these days.

When the user clicks on the favorite icon, a bit of javascript on that page would call favorites.php in the background.  Favorites.php would then issue the SQL call and return a bit of json (using json_encode()) to tell your Javascript code whether or not the SQL was successful.  Your javascript would then react and update the UI accordingly.

jQuery is a very common way to accomplish this, so I'd suggest [a quick google for "jquery ajax tutorial"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery%20ajax%20tutorial&aq=f&oq=).

If you absolutely must support browsers which don't have javascript, the alternative would be for favorites.php to look at the referer:

```
<?php
//do important stuff here
http_redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

However, php's manual indicates that [HTTP_REFERER is not reliable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), so you still may end up with errors.  Ajax for the win.